# Extract specific value from Html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following html table -

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td height=\'30\' bgcolor=\'#CCCACA\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\' color=\'#000000\'><b>&nbsp;Property</b></font>
</td><td bgcolor=\'#CCCACA\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\' color=\'#000000\'><b>&nbsp;Value</b></font>
</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor=\'white\' width=\'200\' height=\'20\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;First Name</font>
</td><td bgcolor=\'white\' width=\'300\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;John</font>
</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor=\'#F3EFEF\' width=\'200\' height=\'20\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;Contact</font>
</td><td bgcolor=\'#F3EFEF\' width=\'300\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;number</font>
</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor=\'white\' width=\'200\' height=\'20\'>
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;Last Name</font>
</td><td bgcolor=\'white\' width=\'300\'><font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;Smith</font>
</td></tr></tr></table>
```

I am looking to use a regular expression in Javascript to extract the `number` value out of this code. My problem being that before every value in the table the line of code -

```
<font size=2 face=\'Arial\'>&nbsp;
```

is present therefore I cannot localise to one value. However I do know that the `number` value will occur after every **6th** instance of the aforementioned line. I am aware a regular expression could extract the values after `&nbsp` how ever not sure how to **1.** Implement this and **2.** Get to the 6th value.

**EDIT**

```
function showProperties2(){

var itemID = new String(objChart.getSelectedElements());
var props = new String(objChart.getItemsPropertyIDs(itemID));
var arrPropIDs = props.split(',');
var propertyHTML="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td height='30' bgcolor='#CCCACA'><font size=2 face='Arial' color='#000000'><b>&nbsp;Property</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#CCCACA'><font size=2 face='Arial' color='#000000'><b>&nbsp;Value</b></font></td></tr>";
var bgcolor="#F3EFEF";
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<arrPropIDs.length;i++){
    if(objChart.getPropertyValue(itemID, arrPropIDs[i])!=""){
        if(bgcolor=="#F3EFEF"){
            bgcolor = "white";
        }else{
            bgcolor = "#F3EFEF";
        }
        propertyHTML+="<tr><td bgcolor='"+bgcolor+"' width='200' height='20'>";
        propertyHTML+= "<font size=2 face='Arial' class='quack'>&nbsp;"+objChart.getPropertyDisplayName(itemID, arrPropIDs[i])+"</font>";
        propertyHTML+="</td><td bgcolor='"+bgcolor+"' width='300'>";
        propertyHTML+= "<font size=2 face='Arial' class='quack2'>&nbsp;"+objChart.getPropertyValue(itemID, arrPropIDs[i])+"</font>";
        propertyHTML+="</td></tr>";
    }
}
propertyHTML+="</tr></table>";
propertyWindow(propertyHTML, "Properties");


}
```

The previous is how I construct my table.

Comment: Is this your own code, or are you being required to work with code that you cannot change that's like this? If it's your code, the easiest way to solve you issue would be to first make it valid HTML, strip out deprecated tags such as `<font>` (replacing with CSS) and then using XPath rather than RegEx to target the value that you want

Comment: REGEX used to parse tag-based languages is generally a bad idea, precisely because, as in this case, if the mark-up is even slightly malformed or unpredictable, the pattern will fail.

Comment: I have created the structured of the HTML myself.

Comment: There shouldn't be any `\'` in real HTML. If this is code from PHP or some other server-side language, you should instead paste the *output* of that, by going to your browser's "View Source" view and grabbing the HTML from there

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[2].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("font")[0].innerHTML` Will give you the required text. But I am not sure what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using jQuery, this might work

```
function getNumber(table) {
    // Set the variable, tableNumber to an error message of sorts
    var tableNumber = "No number found";
    // Loop through all cells
    $(table + ' td').each(function(){
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
        // Tell if a cell contains the text, '&nbsp;Contact'
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('Contact') != -1) {
            // set the variable tableNumber to the text of the next cell
            tableNumber = $(this).next().text();

        }
    });
        return tableNumber;


}

var report = getNumber('#number-table'); //for debugging

alert(report); //for debugging
```

Then call the function like getNumber($('#table-id')) or just getNumber($('table')) if there's no id and there's only one table on the page.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ggnz/1/

Comment: It's not actually missing the row or cell tags, it's just **so** badly formatted that they're easy to miss :)  It does have an extra closing row tag though, which can't be helping!

Comment: @puppybeard this code works great if the table is in the start page, however I have the code working so that the table opens up in a new pop up window, how can I reference this code so that it is not looking at the first document but the pop up window html?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a lot less trouble parsing any HTML document if it's well formatted. You should, to begin with, read up on HTML and CSS. Use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to spot errors in how your code is formatted & what you could do differently. You should be able to get your HTML much cleaner by separating style and format, like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr class="odd">
         <th>Property</th>
         <th>Value</th>
     </tr>
     <tr class="even">
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>John</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="odd">
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>number</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="even">
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<style>
    td {
        color: #000;
        font: Arial;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        height: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #CCCACA;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .even td {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .odd td {
        background-color: #F3EFEF;
    }

    tr td:first-child {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

(At the moment, even though you're specifying shades of grey, the table is rendering for me in blue and turquoise because of the escapes you have going on.)

Then the easiest way to target each "number" cell of your table is to give them a distinct class:

```
<tr>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td class="phoneNumber">(01) 234 5678</td>
</tr>
```

You can then target this in JavaScript with `document.getElementsByClassName("phoneNumber")`, or if you're using jQuery: `$(".phoneNumber")`.

Comment: This looks like a good answer, however I need to edit my question to show you how I have created the table.

Comment: Well I just took the styling that you were applying to content via the `<font>` tag and used CSS in its place. Also, where you were using things like `<td><b>Header</b></td>` for a heading, this should really be `<th>` (Table Heading tag, which is bold by default). The main thing is to keep you mark-up and styles separate as much as possible — it will make it much easier to read, debug and code against

Comment: I have added edits as to how I create the html table, I did not realise that the html was that bad so if you could suggest how I could modify my existing code to suit your suggestion @anotherdave I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'd remove any attributes related to style from the table cells — `bgcolor`, `width`, the `<font>` tags. all these can be replaced by CSS, as above — the idea of a stylesheet is that you come up with a set of rules for how things should look & these are applied throughout your document. It makes it a lot easier to read the code (as there is less clutter), and it's a lot easier to make changes to how things should look. Using 'Times' instead of 'Arial', for example is a one word change. The only other change I'd make would be to remove the last `<tr>` before your closing `</table>` tag.

Comment: Just to say also, when I mentioned that your HTML formatting was bad, I mostly meant the layout. It's generally seen as good practice (especially when asking others about your code) to put a new line for each child tag and to indent by four spaces, outdenting again at the closing tag. It makes it much easier for you (and us) to spot any mistakes or issues, or just to see what's going on.

Comment: I tried your code however it came up in the alert '[object Nodelist]' instead of showing the phone numbere why would this be?

Comment: The jQuery selector `$(".phoneNumber")` above will give you a list of nodes that match — i.e. the `<td>` itself rather than it's value. If you want the text from a node in jQuery, you can use `$(".phoneNumber").text()`, as here: http://jsfiddle.net/vCpGU/